# sort CDs in the least moves

Tags: python, sorting

Input

The input to your program will be a list of CDs which are given in the order that they appear in the starting stack (where the CD that occurs first in the input is at the top of the stack). This will be followed by a blank line, and then the list of the same CDs but in the order they are to appear in the goal. (stack of CDs followed by a blanked line and the goal-list)

Output

Your program should print out a sequence of CDs which Johnny will pull out of the stack so as to sort the stack in the given order. Again, **this sequence of moves must be as short as possible**.

- For example, if the stack has CDs A, B, and C in that order (with A at the top), I may elect to first pull out B. Doing so then changes the order of stack to B, A, and C.

Sample Input 1

```
Eamon McGrath - Peace Maker
Joel Plaskett Emergency - Ashtray Rock
Jimmy Buffett - The Best of Jimmy Buffett
Rural Alberta Advantage - Hometowns
Chuck Mangione - Feels So Good

Rural Alberta Advantage - Hometowns                           
Joel Plaskett Emergency - Ashtray Rock
Eamon McGrath - Peace Maker
Chuck Mangione - Feels So Good
Jimmy Buffett - The Best of Jimmy Buffett
```

Output for Sample Input 1

```
Chuck Mangione - Feels So Good
Eamon McGrath - Peace Maker
Joel Plaskett Emergency - Ashtray Rock
Rural Alberta Advantage - Hometowns
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
lst=[]

while True:
     try: 
          strline = input()
          if len(strline)>0:
               lst.append(strline)
          if strline == "END":
               lst.pop()
               break
     except:
          break


#print(len(lst))  #this will print size 10  for sample input #1
x=len(lst)//2
stacklist=lst[:x]  #print(lst[:x])  the stack of CDs that is not ordered
goal=lst[x:]       #print(lst[x:])  this will print the goal

index_lst=random.randrange(len(lst)-1)
index_stacklist=random.randrange(1,(len(lst)//2))

steps=[]
while stacklist != goal:
     stacklist.insert(0,stacklist.pop(index_stacklist)) #pick a CD and put it on the top
     steps.append(stacklist.pop(index_stacklist)) #append the move to a list

print(steps) # print the steps out
```

I am confused why this is giving me out of range,
 and I don't really know how to sort the stacklist to the goal list in the least steps.
since it's sorted in favor of CDs not alphabetically according to the input.

Comment: Hint: Some of the CDs (at least 1) are already in their final order.